# What percentage error?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, sensor, error

**A transducer with an internal resistance of 10 k Ohm generates an output voltage 
which is sensed by a voltmeter having an internal resistance of 30 k Ohm. What 
percentage error is to be expected? How can Engineer fix this error?**

Comment: By going to her/his TA for homework help.... :(

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. We will help you if you show you have tried and have got stuck on a particular point. YOU need to show that you have put in some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally one chooses a better DMM than using an analog meter with a certain Ohm/volt inverse current transfer function or in this case a fixed R.

An Engineer would simply correct the Load regulation error to compute the correct value using inverse impedance ratio..

So if true sensor out was 1V with 10k then a 30k load would divide the and you expect sense voltage Vs= (30/30+10) * 1= 750mV = 3/4 * Vs thus corrected reading is 4/3 is the correction factor.

or use a 1MOhm DMM then your correction factor is 1% higher which is slightly larger or significant than the accuracy of cheap devices nut perhaps less significant on the resistor tolerance, so often we ignore it unless accuracy is critical.

Does that make sense?